# Pushwoosh Duplicate entry error in android studio

Tags: android, duplicates, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, pushwoosh

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/arellomobile/android/push/utils/rich/WebImageView.class

### Here is my app.gradle:

Where is the problem and How to remove that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app.gradle did not attach. Make sure you are referencing the Pushwoosh library only once. It looks like it has been referenced twice somehow.